# How to determine the process that's killing a Celery task

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, terminate

I have a long-running [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html) task that processes a file. Occassionally, I'll get an error email from it reading:

```
Task tasks.process_file with id 17cba17a-b79b-4629-9e8c-1bde4b73b447 raised exception:
'Terminated(15,)'


Task was called with args: (30L,) kwargs: {}.

The contents of the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1668, in _set_terminated
    raise Terminated(-(signum or 0))
Terminated: 15
```

I have no code that would purposefully terminate these tasks, nor do I understand why the operating system would terminate them. The server has 16GB of memory, only half of which is in use at any given time, so I don't think the OS would terminate due to low resources.

I've checked `dmesg` but it contains no reference to these terminations.

How do I determine what's terminating this tasks and stop it?

Comment: usually this is caused by the kernel invoking the OOM (out of memory) killer - are you sure there is nothing in dmesg or /var/log/<whatever> about this? even if you have a lot of memory, if there is a serious memory leak in your code it could suddenly consume all the available memory and be killed in the space of a few seconds.

Comment: @scytale, What should I look for?  `dmesg | grep -i terminat` finds nothing. I wouldn't know what to look for in `/var/log/*`. My application's logs only include the error I've already seen.

Comment: run `dmesg -T | less` and see what crops up around the time your tasks were killed. Do the same in `/var/log/kern` or `/var/log/system` or whatever (which one it is depends on your distro). google around to  see what oom messages look like. if you're not sure what a log message means pop it into google. you'll have to do some detective work here.